# Is there a word for someone who won't think critically?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a word for someone who won't think through issues and instead comes to others hoping that they will think for them and solve problems for them?  A word that is more specific to a lack of critical thinking skills than "lazy"?

Comment: on Stack Overflow and some other online forums, there is the concept of a [help vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)....

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - are you more interested in the lack of *ability* to think logically, or the lack of *desire* to do so?  I.e., stupid vs lazy?

Comment: The lack of desire, but I was hoping for something a little more specific to someone who refuses to think than lazy...but still something along those lines

Comment: *uncritical* refers to being superficial and not analyzing or looking in detail at something. But it does not imply doing so out of laziness. It sounds like you are looking for being uncritical out of laziness, not out of **inability** to be critical.

Comment: Yes, those people are dependent. Dunno a noun for them. There are many reasons why people can't think for themselves, mostly because they are too neurotic and only believe in what the "other" says due to their own psychic and psychological dependency on others. Like every problem in life, they think other people can solve whatever their problem is instead of trying to figure it out themselves.

Comment: Calling someone a "mental slacker" would probably wake them up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could call them a [**lemming**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lemming).

Meaning one who follows a leader unthinkingly, possibly to their own demise. So, this person does not think for themselves and instead looks to one they consider a leader to do their thinking for them (possibly to their own detriment).

Alternatively, along the same lines, you could call them a [**sheep**](http://thefreedictionary.com/sheep), following the second definition:

> 2. a.  A person regarded as timid, weak, or submissive.
>
> b.  One who is easily swayed or led.

Comment: How does this describe someone who is too lazy to think through a problem and wants someone else to do it for them? Can you expand on your answer?

Comment: Edited to expand upon answer. I admit lemming does not refer specifically to a lack of critical thinking skills, but it seems @Heather is asking for a word for one who chooses not to think for themselves and looks for another to do their thinking, rather than one who is unable to do their own thinking, so I believe "lemming" is applicable.

Comment: I see where you're coming from now! I'm more used to these people being called _sheep_ and as I've been typing this you've added that definition +1

Answer (score 1):

The person in the scenario that you have portrayed isn't necessarily lacking the ability of **critical thinking** and is very much as you say, ***lazy***. But to answer the question:

According to Cambridge Dictionary:
***Critical Thinking*** means: the process of thinking carefully about a subject or idea, without allowing feelings or opinions to affect you.
Which basically means ***objective, unbiased or disinterested*** in one's thinking and analysis.
The opposite of it could be ***biased, subjective or emotional thinking*.**
The opposite of critical thinking can also be ***uncritical thinking***.

If by critical thinking the writer loosely means - the ability of *logical analysis* (even though there are clear distinctions), then the person might be ***illogical***.

If by *critical thinking* the writer loosely means the quality of carefully and logically assessing claims or statements to evaluate their beliefs and position, then the opposite might be ***dogmatic, narrow-minded, intransigent, doctrinaire.***

Answer (score 0):

The term ***simple-minded*** comes to mind.

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/simple-minded) defines it as:

> Lacking in subtlety or sophistication; artless or naive

More often than not, *simple-minded* individuals will lack critical thinking.

Comment: I agree with your assertion that _simple-minded_ individuals tend to lack critical thinking but that doesn't mean that people who lack critical thinking are simple-minded. The term tends to be used as an insult, anyway, which I doubt is what the OP is looking for.